Is it permissible to invent these kinds of worships in Islam?
Asalamalaikum. People invent endless worships but obviously based on arguments from the religion. For example. There is no hadith that says supplicate to Allah to do well in school exams. But it goes without saying that man is allowed to invent this worship because there is a hadith that says ask Allah for table salt if you need it. I am not talking about saying that it is sunnah of the messenger to this and that act at this and that time because obviously that would be bidah. I am simply talking about inventing new ways to express love, respect and gratitude towards Allah.
Is it permissible to invent these kinds of worships in Islam that i have written below? Please look at the examples below. For example: Someone says that he will stand for an hour as a sign of respect and gratitude to Allah? Or someone says he will walk for two hours as a sign of love and respect for Allah. Or someone says that he will express his respect and love for Allah by sitting on the couch for two hours. Or someone says I will express my love and respect for Allah by thinking for an hour only about religion and Allah. Or someone says that for an hour I will write subhanallah, alhamdulilah repeatedly to express love and respect for Allah. Because there is a hadith that says that works are evaluated according to the intention. If the intention is good, then what is the problem here?

Though I do understand thinking about religion and Allah is a highly encouraged worship of Allah, and writing down His names and praise is also a worship, but how walking or standing steal might be a sign of love to Allah? ... Yes, if you would walk as an exercise to keep your gifted body healthy that would be considered as a practical kind of praise (شکر), but walking only as a direct sign of worship is not clear to me what that means. Am I missing a point?

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-flagellation . As far as I understand, intentionally hurting and damaging yourself is haram in Islam, implying that abusing drugs is also haram, even if not explicitly stated for each harmful drug by fully naming it.

@GyroGearloose, "intentionally hurting and damaging yourself is haram in Islam" is correct when there is no profound gain in return. For example one may give his life to save two other lives, and this is not necessarily Haram if it is intentionally, but e.g. committing suicide is among the greatest sins in Islam. Some scholars might even classify simple smoking as sin as they see no gain in return from smoking, while other scholars may only discourage smoking, so not all scholars have a same idea in all cases.

Something that might be more relevant to the question asked by OP, can perhaps be Nidhr (النذر), which means someone asks Allah for a request and in return makes a deed obligatory for himself/herself which will not be obligatory the otherwise. For example one might say I will fast all the Fridays for two years if my child will survive his present sever illness. However, even Nidhr have some constraints, like e.g. the deed should have an intrinsic benefit in it, like helping the others, or anything encouraged in Islam, and "a mere climbing 5 lampposts" seems not acceptable in that regard :)

Even as I do not know much about Islam, it is very obvious that the Quran and the Hadith is quite complete about how to worship Allah, and Allah only.
Quite different of that is what you do to please Allah, by gathering good deeds, which is very different from worship.
And, your examples, do not benefit anyone. Just wast your time and energy that you could spend on approved ways as feeding the poor or doing other good deeds.

+1, good answer, however, as far as I can say, "pleasing Allah by gathering good deeds" is indeed worship of Allah, and even among the greatest ones, because of the intention! Even there are famous scholarly sayings like "عبادت بجز خدمت خلق نیست" translated into "worshiping is no more than serving mankind (Literary impressionistic or expressionistic talking)"

@owari not sure about doing good deeds is worshiping Allah. Can not even kafir do good deeds? Especially those who were not told about Allah and Quran?

that's why I added "because of the intention!", as you yourself had stated "to please Allah, by gathering good deeds", and a kafir is not intending to Please Allah. Otherwise in history of religion there are people with a resume full of good deeds that are among the most wrongdoers in view of religion, Samiri (سامریّ) being one according to Ahadeeth.

those who do not know Allah and Quran, maybe know Him through other heavenly religion like Christianity or Judaism, and that would suffice. Those who do not know anything about Heavenly religion yet might believe in a name of Allah, like the Truth (حقّ), and their deeds in that regard might also suffice as far as I can say, and Allah knows best. There is a Hadeeth from Imam Hussain PBUH at the last seconds of his life in Karbala, that warned the enemies by calling them to at least be liberal (free from desires in the main life stream) if you have no religion.
